# Is there a way to add a custom file to my VueJS build output

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

I believe the topic title is self-explanatory, but I want to specify my use case.

I need a way to add a custom build file to my VueJS build output.

**Why:**
Well, I'm building a SPA application, and I'm using Netlify as my hosting service. And for me to use Vue-router in mode history, I need a proper server setup to redirect all the routes to the /index.html route.
And to do so in Netlify, I need to add a `_redirects` file to my build output directory.
[Source](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/).

**Note:**
I know I can do this manually after every build, but I need to automate the process as I'm using a build command in Netlify that can take the source code of my client app and turns it into a static build directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) for that.

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

plugins: [

    ...

    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { 
                from: '/path/to/_redirects.file', 
                to: '/path/to/destination' 
            },
        ],
    }),

    ...

],
```

Comment: Thanks, also someone else reminded me that I can use the public folder for that. Do you think there is a difference between the two means?